# Difference when rendering maps among localhost and kubernetes env

Tags: openmaptiles, tileserver-gl, tileserver

I've been running a tileserver-gl to server maps renderization over kubernetes cluster. The problem is, I have a certain class of road (motorway_construction) that needs to be shown at any zoom level. When I run tileserver-gl locally, no problem happens, but when I deploy my style to my k8s cluster the same road only appears only at a certain zoom range, even my style.json not containing the specific configuration for this behavior.

Here some pics of both envs:

Road renderization:

[Construction road how should appears (local render)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4N5D.png)

[Construction road not rendering (K8s cluster)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWiFR.png)

---

Here it is my style.json file:
https://www.coderstool.com/cs/DqL8Ha

I use exactly the same file locally and in k8s, but the behaviour is different.

Is there something I could do to solve this issue?